# Angular unit test factory that uses http request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am working on an angular js app with karma/Jasmine testing framework, I need to test a factory that returns a http promise but it always return undefined

here is my factory

```js
angular.module('GithubUsers').factory('Users',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){
  return{
    getAllUsers:function(){
      var defered= $q.defer();
      $http({
        url:'https://api.github.com/users',
        method:'GET'
      }).then(function(users){
        defered.resolve(users.data);
      },function(err){
        defered.reject(err);
      })
      return defered.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

here is my tests

**Update** thanks to your answers I modified my code to the following but no I got this error

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"status":0,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://api.github.com/users?since=1","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"cached":false},"statusText":""} thrown

```js
describe('Test Users Factory',function(){
  var $controller,
  Users,
  $rootScope,
  $httpBackend,
  $q;
  beforeEach(module('GithubUsers'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_,_Users_,_$rootScope_,_$httpBackend_,_$q_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
    Users = _Users_;
    $rootScope= _$rootScope_;
    $httpBackend=_$httpBackend_;
    
   
  }))
  
  it('should get users',function(){
   
    var result;

    $httpBackend.whenGET('https://api.github.com/users?since=1').respond(function(){
       return {data:[{id:2}],status:200};
    })
    Users.getAllUsers().then(function(res){
      result = res;
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $rootScope.$digest()
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  })
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass a function that returns a  **array with 3 items** in it, to whenGET().**respond**().

Maybe, you can try something like this:

```
 beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (User, $httpBackend, $http) {
    ...
    this.withOKUsers = function() {
            var i1 = new User();
            i1.id = 10;
            return [200, JSON.stringify([ i1]), {}];
    } ...
}));
...    
it('should get users',function(){
$httpBackend
    .whenGET('https://api.github.com/users')
    .respond(this.withOKUsers);

Users.getAllUsers().then(function(res){
  result = res;
});    

$httpBackend.flush(); 
expect(result).not.toBeNull();
...
```

(I prefer to arrange spec outside of it() clause for better readability)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it didn't worked for me

Comment: indeed forgot to add flush() method. Flush always between  then callback and your expectations

Comment: have you tried returning [200, JSON.stringify()... ] in respond function? I don't think the digest is needed, here

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a **$httpBackend.flush();** call after your test method call. It will invoke a success/error or then part and resolve a $q's promise properly. For more tests I would move a $httpBackend.whenGET to each test case separately so I can later verify it per use case but it's just my personal opinion.

I find it a little suspicious that you mix a $controller and a factory in one test. I would suggest to split them, and in controller test just check the calls to service methods and in a facotry test itself do a $httpBackend stuff.

Below I paste your test with my corrections. It works now for me:

```
describe('Test Users Factory', function () {
var Users,
$rootScope,
$httpBackend,
$q;
beforeEach(module('app.utils'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_Users_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _$q_) {
    Users = _Users_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}));

afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

it('should get users', function () {
    var result;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', "https://api.github.com/users").respond({ data: [{ id: 2 }], status: 200 });

    Users.getAllUsers().then(function (res) {
        result = res;
        expect(result).toBeTruthy();
    });


    $httpBackend.flush();
    $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Important notices: 
1)afterEach - check if no pending requests remain after your call
2) your url differ with a parameter ?since=1. But you do not give it as a parameter in your code so i do not understand why you added this parameter. 
Maybe consider string concatenation with url and parameter ?

Comment: Thanks so much for clarification I didn't know about `flush` function before could you please check my updated question